# how to create composite route in $stateProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

If I go to /settings/wizard/hv then I see only Settings Page. what am I doing wrong?
I have Page: "Settings" url: '/settings'
on page button.handler > go to url: '/settings/wizard'

I have this code:

```
    $stateProvider
            .state('settings', {
                url: '/settings',
                template: '<div>Settings panel with fields</div>',
                title: 'Конфигурация',
                controller: function(){
                    console.log('controller settings')
                }
            })

            .state('settings.wizard', {
                url: '/wizard',
                abstract: true,
                template: '<ui-view></ui-view>',
                title: 'Мастер настройки',
                /** @ngInject */
                controller: function($state, $scope, $controller){
                    console.log('controller Wizard');
                    if($scope.mode == 'vw'){
                        $state.go('settings.wizard.vw')
                    }else{
                        $state.transitionTo('settings.wizard.hv')
                    }
                }
            })

            .state('settings.wizard.hv', {
                url: '/hv',
                parent: 'settings.wizard',
                templateUrl: 'app/plugins/settings/wizard/tpl/wizard.html',
                title: 'Мастер настройки',
                /** @ngInject */
                controller: function ($controller, $scope) {
                    console.log('controller wizard/hv')
                    $scope.mode = 'hv';
                    var ctrl = $controller('Settings.Wizard');
                    ctrl.setMode('hv');
                },
                controllerAs: 'wizard'
            })
            .state('settings.wizard.vw', {
                url: '/vw',
                // parent: 'settings.wizard',
                templateUrl: 'app/plugins/settings/wizard/tpl/wizard.html',
                title: 'Мастер настройки',
                /** @ngInject */
                controller: function ($controller, $scope) {
                    console.log('controller wizard/vw')
                    $scope.mode = 'hv';
                    var ctrl = $controller('Settings.Wizard');
                    ctrl.setMode('vw');
                },
                controllerAs: 'wizard'
            });
```

on Page '/settings/wizard/hv' I have some subPages and Views

```
<div>
  settings > wizard > hv
  <input />
  <ui-view></ui-view>
  <button onclick="$state.go('settings.wizard.hv.servers')" >go to servers</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The question is very unclear. Can you explain it better and post more code pls?

Comment: I add more code

Comment: Смотри, у тебя в шаблоне state `settings` нет ui-view. Куда следующий стейт (дочерний) будет рендериться то?

Comment: дак в том то и прикол, что мне нужно не внутрь этой страницы рендерить Мастер, а скорее вместо него (или поверх него)
При этом контроллер Settings подготавливает некоторые переменные в $scope для Wizard/hv | vw

Comment: Так оно не работает. Если следующий стейт - дочерний, он ищет ui-view в родителе.

Comment: А как тогда можно такое реализовать? Я уже все волосы себе повыдирал в поисках варианта

Comment: Это немного выходит за рамки данного топика. :) Если совсем труба, найди меня в скайпе по моему нику. Попробую помочь.

Comment: может в $routeProvider это возможно как-то обыграть?

Comment: Я думаю, что вся проблема в неверно составленной иерархии. Просто не очень понятно чего ты хочешь добиться, заменяя родительский стейт - дочерним. Может быть тебе стоит обратить внимание на `named views` https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

Comment: писанул в скайп тебе. Мульти вьюхи я смотрел, но это не мой случай, вся загвоздка именно в маршрутах в адресной строке. 
Я использую Мастера в разных разделах свои и они подменяют собой Основную форму (при елании пользователя)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, try to add ui-view to your `settings` state template:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('settings', {
            url: '/settings',
            template: '<section><div>Settings panel with fields</div><div ui-view></div></section>',
            title: 'Конфигурация',
            controller: function(){
                console.log('controller settings')
            }
        })
```

Child states requires a spot to render into.